# How to send objets from one rule to other with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, rules

I'm trying to **scrape** Glassdoor company rating, and at some point, I need to send some objects from one rule to the other.

This is the main link for the search: https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/lisbon-reviews-SRCH_IL.0,6_IM1121.htm

I access this page on the first Rule, get some information, then I need to go to another link from this page, to enter into the reviews page following the XPath expression //a[@class='eiCell cell reviews '].

Here is the problem, how can I follow this link with the XPath expression, inside the parse_item  without losing the information that I got?

```
class GetComentsSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'get_coments'
allowed_domains = ['www.glassdoor.com']
start_urls = ['http://https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/portugal-reviews-SRCH_IL.0,8_IN195.htm/']
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
download_delay = 0.1


rules = (
    #Acess the page, get the link from each company and move to parse_item
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class=' margBotXs']/a"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//a[@class='eiCell cell reviews ']"), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
     
    #Pagination
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//li[@class='next']/a"), follow=True),
    
    
)



def parse_item(self, response):
    #get company name and rating
    name = response.xpath("(//span[@class='updateBy'])[1]").get()
    rating = response.xpath("//span[@class='bigRating strong margRtSm h1']/text()").get()
    
    #Here i need to go to the link of //a[@class='eiCell cell reviews '] to get more data
    #without losing the name and rating
    
    yield {
        "Name" : name,
        "Rating" : rating
        }
```

Comment: `yield Request(url, callback='other_parser', meta={"item": your_item})` and later in other parser `your_item = response.meta['item']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send to other parser usin `Request(..., meta=...)`

(and you don't need `Rule` to get url for this request)

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    name = response.xpath("(//span[@class='updateBy'])[1]").get()
    rating = response.xpath("//span[@class='bigRating strong margRtSm h1']/text()").get()

    item = {
        "Name" : name,
        "Rating" : rating
    }

    url = ... #Here i need to go to the link of //a[@class='eiCell cell reviews '] to get more data

    yield Request(url, callback='other_parser', meta={"item": item})

def other_parser(self, response):  
    item = response.meta['item']

    item['other'] = ... # add values to item 

    yield item
```